# Does kubernetes rolling update may impact applications running in pods or not?

Tags: kubernetes, upgrade

Does kubernetes rolling update may impact applications running in pods or not? This is simple question which I don't see an answer in documentation. Does my application have to be designed to support k8s rolling update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application needs to be designed in a way that survives termination of the process. Be it graceful or not. In that it does not really differ for regular application, where you want it to survive (ie. not corrupt data, not loose state if it is stateful) when server is for example unexpectedly powered down. Running it on cluster you are probably already aware that deployments are intended to run multiple instances of an app in parallel, so your app needs to survive that as well.

Now, that does not mean you can't make it behave better in some cases, like ie. add some termination handling when SIGKILL is received, but that is not exactly kube specific as well.

Comment: What is exact set of signals k8s sends to pods containers, can you post link pls?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your existing PODs will be terminated and re-create the new PODs with new image.  You can specify `maxUnavailable` and `maxSurge` to control the rolling update process. Also make sure your application has health check URL defined.

Comment: My question was more on application impact. Does my app have to be built to handle pod termination and continuation on another pod or k8s can maintain it transparently? Can you point to relevant topics in k8s docs?

Comment: kubernetes takes  30 seconds to terminate the pod. When you deploy the pod configure the livenessProbe in your deployment yaml file. Also in this page they have sample example for livenessProbe. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/